# Limit of question to answer ratio

Tags: discussion

I bet this topic was on before, but I haven't found anything like what I want to ask / recommend.

As a programmer, I'm mostly active on Stack Overflow, it has helped me countless times. Therefore I try to give some of my knowledge back, I try to find some time to answer a question or two at least once a week.

I have seen many occurrences where users, I have learned that they're called moochers, have 1k+ reputation, mostly generated from their many questions. Usually, they have very little answers, sometimes the ratio is worse than 1/10 and many of the answers I have checked are often times bad quality.

I don't have a problem with helping them, although I was very discouraged after the following incident. I had some free time and I saw a question, which looked a bit like a school assignment, although I wasn't sure. As I had the spare time, I decided to help, just to receive bunch of subquestions which asked for minor changes in logic of my initial example. I first told them it's simple and what should the to change, describing the solution, I just didn't want do serve it, with a mindset nothing is learned if I just provide (copy-paste ready) code. I got a very disrespectful response, basically it felt like they are trying to call me dumb. I decided to still help, so edit the answer to include code they wanted and be done with it. After that, nothing, no response, no upvote. And when I checked back next day, question was gone. I absolutely do not expect to be praised or anything, but I believe some basic respect and maybe a thanks or just an upvote if I was helpful isn't too much to ask.

I have rumbled enough here and haven't gotten to the point, which is how to deal with those people -- help them, ignore them or do something else?

<s>I also mentioned a recommendation, I was thinking of a limit for question-to-answers ratio, so everyone has to "give something back" before asking more questions. And it has to be a quality answer, it has to get an upvote or be accepted to prevent spamming with useless answers. Or maybe someone else has even better idea on how to stop this behavior. Although on the other hand, users like these could always create new accounts and get over the limitation.</s>

There might already exist a mechanism similar to that recommended, I must admit I'm not familiar since I rarely ever ask a question.

**Edit:** When reading it again, I have realized I worded my recommendation badly, I don't know what exactly I was going at, but I agree with the answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My recommendation is - stay as-is. A good question is still useful information, regardless of who asked it. We're not here to serve individual users, we're here to build up a repository of useful questions and their associated answers, so that other people can find the solutions to their problems.

Sure, getting upvotes is nice and all, but providing useful information to help current and future visitors should be the motivation. Individual user scores and reputations should come secondary to the actual content.

Provided the question was useful and well asked, and your answer was correct and relevant then everything is working as it should.

As for whether there should be a required ratio of questions:answers per user; **absolutely not**. Anything that puts any impediments into peoples way from asking useful questions or answering other questions that they know the answer to is 'a bad thing'. There are already blocks in place to stop people repeatedly asking *bad* questions. But there shouldn't be anything in place to just put limits on overall volume of questions. A good question is still a good question, even if it's been asked by an ungrateful moron.

Vote on good questions, flag bad ones, answer those you know the answers to and be happy that you're part of a big repository of useful information that helps future users.

Answer (score 6):

I don't like this idea at all.  The Q&A economy is inevitably one in which there are people who mostly answer questions and people who mostly ask them.  That is how expertise works.  I know a lot about the subject, and I help people who do not.

I agree there is a spectrum with regard to how gracious people are about receiving help, and it is annoying to provide an answer, clarify via comments, provide edits, and then finally get, "Great, that's exactly what I need!" but no upvote or tick.  However, those people generally either don't participate that much, or else eventually get with the program.

There are also ways to deal with particular hard cases; **if you notice a pattern with someone, go to chat and mention it.**  As a moderator I've "superpinged" people to drag them into a private chat and explain the general philosophy and what the purpose of various rules are.  The response to this is usually positive and in at least one instance I've seen someone go from being a bane to exemplary overnight.  If that doesn't work, there are further steps, such as rate limiting how often someone can ask a question.

The most serious problem I see with your recommendation is that it will encourage *even worse* behaviour -- e.g., people ripping out crap answers just to keep their ratio correct.  It is simply too crude a mechanism, and again, I disagree with the premise that someone who only asks questions and never answers them is by definition an undesirable participant.

Comment: I agree on the spamming part and I have explicitly pointed it out. I have also edited the question to because when re-reading it, it's not exactly what I wanted to say and now I don't know what I actually did want to express. About the last part, there are of course many great questions and I wasn't targeting users who are curious enough to ask those. I was talking about users who just asks questions related to their very specific problem, or often times worse, their school assignment, doesn't provide a question which would help many users to come.

Comment: There are mechanisms for putting truly problem cases in check, but they are not completely automated and IMO they shouldn't be -- an actual person or persons should take responsibility for decisions like rate limiting someone, etc.  I can't promise it will always work, but again, it is not uncommon (at least some places) for people to raise these issues in chat, get a bit of consensus, and have a mod deal with it.